Inheritance tax on a trust (usa)
There are many questions related to trust and inheritance tax, but from the ones I read, one thing is not clear to me:
If one trustee dies when the net worth of a revocable trust exceeds Oregon's threshold (currently only one million dollars), does the other trustee (or the trust itself) have to pay Oregon’s inheritance tax?  What about federal, if it exceeds that threshold?
Put another way, if one trustee dies, and the other gives away enough to get below the threshold (but not enough to trigger the gift tax), does estate tax apply, or is it deferred until the other trustee is gone and the successors distribute the residue?
My mother-in-law's revocable trust had to pay inheritance taxes but she was widowed and there was no surviving co-trustee.  So our trust is a slightly different situation.
Currently, the net worth is slightly above the Oregon threshold and FAR below the federal threshold.  Certain things/funds we have designated for her children and certain things for mine.  If one of us passes, the other will distribute that person's planned inheritance, which will make it below the threshold.

When you use the word trust, do you mean an irrevocable trust? If the trust is revocable then for tax purposes, the trust is a disregarding entity.

It's revocable but I don't know the meaning of disregarding entity.  I do know that my mother-in-law's revocable trust had to pay inheritance taxes but she was widowed and there was no surviving co-trustee.

The term disregarding entity means that, for legal purposes it does not exist.
Since your mother-in-law's trust is revocable, for tax purposes the money held in the trust will be considered her assets and as such the assets in the trust would be subject to inheritance tax and Federal Estate tax. Assuming the estate assets are over the exclusion amount, the Federal Estate tax rate is 40%.
While there maybe no co-trustee, it is likely there is a successor trustee. That is, in the event that all the  trustees cannot perform their  duties than the successor trustee becomes a trustee.
You wrote:
does the other trustee (or the trust itself) have to pay Oregon’s inheritance tax?
My response:
The trustee will not have to pay any inheritance tax. The trust, the estate, or the beneficiary(or beneficiaries) might.
I am not familiar with the inheritance tax in Oregon.
I hope that a lawyer has been retained to help with the situation.

Almost an answer.  Put another way, if one trustee dies, and the other gives away enough to get below the threshold (but not enough to trigger the gift tax), does estate tax apply, or is it deferred until the other trustee is gone and the successors distribute the residue?

@WGroleau Taking off a trustee will not affect tax. Taking off a beneficiary might. However, there are normally restrictions on trustees making gifts. Gifting money by an estate to charity would definitely reduce the estate tax liability. However, the beneficiaries of the estate might complain.

@WGroleau trustees can't just gift trust assets away, that would be a violation of their fiduciary duty. Trustees must follow the trust document and execute what's in it, they cannot just do what they want.

We are the trustees and the trustors.  Our fiduciary duty is to ourselves and we have the power to change the trust documents at any time.  The point of the question is to minimize the need to make changes when anticipated events occur.

When the events occur you may not be able to make any changes anymore, that's the point of the trust.

@WGroleau Are there two  current beneficiaries of the revocable trust? Are the two beneficiaries of the revocable trust married to each other?

@littleadv, Right—when both of us are gone, the successor trustees cannot make changes.  But when one of us passes, the survivor doesn't want to find out then that he/she should have made this or that change earlier.  Thus, questions like this.

@Bob, depends on how you define beneficiaries.  As long as my wife and/or I are alive, we are the beneficiaries.  Afterward, our four children are the beneficiaries to the extent we have defined.  But I don't see that as relevant to my question.

@WGroleau At the death of first current beneficiary (you or your  wife) the remaining beneficiary might want to disclaim assets and have them go to your kids. Actually, you could setup the living revocable trust such that if  the  remaining spouse does not want all the assets they go into a bypass trust. This has the  protentional for big savings on Federal Estate tax when the second spouse passes depending on how much you and your wife have in terms of assets

@WGroleau A classic way to avoid estate tax is to leave money to a spouse. That is why I asked if  the current beneficiaries are married to each other.

Ah, well, technically, it is left to the spouse, since the trust specifies everything goes to the kids when both of us are gone.  But I was planning to actually give her kids their part if she passed rather than make them wait for me to say good-bye.  And vice versa.

@WGroleau Under current law, if estate tax is not an issue, by making your kids wait for the second spouse to die, will get them the advantage of step-up in basis at the death of the second spouse. However, depending on how much  you have, it might result in a significant increase in your Federal Estate tax liability and maybe at the state level also.

We'll have to consider that.  But estate tax (Oregon) will be an issue unless we distribute some of it as gifts earlier.

Once the estate is created (by the death of your mother-in-law), the Oregon estate tax is computed based on the value of the estate. The estate giving away money does not change this and does nothing to help much of anybody in the tax department. Also remember that the incremental tax rate starts at 10% of the value of 1 million, so giving away, say 500,000 to save 50,000 isn't very useful.

@JonCuster It is my understanding, but I have to admit I am not sure, that  you can reduce the Oregon estate tax by gifting to charity after the person has died but before the estate is settled. You can look at  here for more information:  https://estateplanning.osbar.org/files/2022/08/Est_2022Summer.pdf If you  think I am wrong about that, please tell me why.

@Bob - Perhaps, but is it actually worthwhile? Selling assets for cash may mean the estate pays capital gains, while the heirs get the step up in basis. The estate may save 10% but the heir's tax savings by making that donation themselves is likely far greater. Run the numbers for various scenarios.

@JonCuster It is almost certainly not worth while.
